# How to push json data the is divided to pages to the same object when scrolling down in angular2?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular2-services

> How to push json data which is divided to pages, to the same object when
> scrolling down in angular2?
>
> ```
> The Fuctions in the component
> ```

```
getMyPlaysWithParams(): void {
          //this.spinnerService.show();
          this.myPlaysService.getPlaysWithParams(this.periodType, this.searchType, this.stationId, this.cPeriod, this.page)
            .subscribe(myPlaysSearchOne => {
              this.myPlaysSearchOne = myPlaysSearchOne;
             }),error => this.errorMessage = <any>error;
      }
      getMyPlaysWithParamsPerPage(): void {
          //this.spinnerService.show();
          this.myPlaysService.getMyPlaysWithParamsPerPage(this.periodType, this.searchType, this.stationId, this.cPeriod, this.page).subscribe(myPlaysSearchOne => {
              this.myPlaysSearchOne = myPlaysSearchOne;
             }),
              error => this.errorMessage = <any>error;
      }
```

> ```
>     The service that makes the http.get
> ```

```
getPlaysWithParams(period:string,searchType:string,stationId:string,startDate:string,page:string): Observable<MyPlaysSearchOne> {
              let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
              if(stationId ==='0'){
                 params.set('period',period);
                 params.set('searchType',searchType);
                 params.set('startDate',startDate);
                 params.set('page',page);
               }else{
                 params.set('period',period);
                 params.set('searchType',searchType);
                 params.set('stationId',stationId);
                 params.set('startDate',startDate);`enter code here`
                 params.set('page',page);
              }
                return this.http.get(this.localPath+this.sessionId, {search: params})
                        .map(response => <MyPlaysSearchOne>response.json());
        
            }
             getMyPlaysWithParamsPerPage(period:string,searchType:string,stationId:string,startDate:string,page:string): Observable<MyPlaysSearchOne>{
              let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
              if(stationId ==='0'){
                 params.set('period',period);
                 params.set('searchType',searchType);
                 params.set('startDate',startDate);
                 params.set('page',page);
               }else{
                 params.set('period',period);
                 params.set('searchType',searchType);
                 params.set('stationId',stationId);
                 params.set('startDate',startDate);
                 params.set('page',page);
              }
                return this.http.get(this.localPath+this.sessionId, {search: params}).map(response => <MyPlaysSearchOne>response.json());
            }
```

> json object

```
      page: number;
      stationId: number;
      searchType: number;
      numOfPages: number;
      sumOfPlays: number;
      currentPeriod: {
        period: number,
        endDate: string,
        startDate: string,
        periodInx: number,
        periodName: string
      };
        creations: {
           endTime: string,
           startTime: string,
           stationUrl: string,
           acumId: string,
           stationId: string,
           startDate: string,
           name: string,
           languageId: number,
           performer: string
        };
```

> what I'm trying to do is get more json data and display it in the same list
> when scrolling down. how do I push the data to the same
> object? I don't know to reference it , it appears to be
> empty(this.myPlaysSearchOne) when I log it. please HELP!

Comment: If I were to be in your position then, I would have returned the JSON result as an array and then  push the data like this `this.myPlaysSearchOne.push(myPlaysSearchOne)` provided `this.myPlaysSearchOne` is an array

Comment: Thanks, I've tried and it's still not working